# Sort NSNumber with NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a Route as my top level Core Data entity.  Then a Route has Locations.  The Locations have a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *index;
```

I need the index because I need to make sure the user's route is in order.  I was wondering how I can best sort on the Locations entity.  In my tableView, I show the name of the Route.  Then when the user clicks on the Route, I show the Locations.  I saw NSSet has

```
sortedArrayUsingDescriptors
```

but I wasn't aware of how I could sort NSNumber with a sortDescriptor.  I have seen people just use code like

```
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:) // or something like that
```

I can write a simple convenience method to iterate through the NSSet and return the Location objects by their index, but wasn't sure if there was a better way.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this as your sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor* sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
```

This will sort you location objects in ascending order by the value of their NSNumber* index property.

Comment: You don't need the `integerValue`, sort descriptors work well with `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this: `[set allObjects]sortedArrayUsing...` and sort it with whatever normal array sort method you want.

Answer (score 0):

The better answer, use `index`, sometime will crash. I don't know why, but use `self` well.

```
NSSortDescriptor* sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
```